# Docker: What are the new Linux Container on Windows (LCOW) with Linuxkit

Tags: linux, windows, docker

What is the difference between current Linux Container and the future Linux Cotnainer on Windows?
Is Linuxkit currently used?

I'am using the current version of Docker for Windows: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/

Questions:

1. When i look into Hyper-V I can see one VM: MobyLinuxVM
   Does this vm was build with Linuxkit?
2. Is the future architecture to have multiple vms, each hosting one container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wondered the same and while the documentation is sparse (along [with some name changing](https://www.mirantis.com/blog/ok-i-give-up-is-docker-now-moby-and-what-is-linuxkit/) going on) and the answer depends on the exact time of inspection (since Docker on Windows just underwent major changes) i would say

> MobyLinuxVM Does this vm was build with Linuxkit?

The [Docker Blog](https://blog.docker.com/2017/11/docker-for-windows-17-11/) states that `as of Docker for Windows 17.10 this VM is based on LinuxKit`. The process for older versions of Docker for Windows (or for older Versions of Windows: everything not Windows Server 1709 und Windows 10 Fall Creators Update) was different ([Docker Toolbox](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/)) as it used VirtualBox to run a [boot2docker](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker) image. Alongside the change of the root VM image were some other changes (e.g. where the docker daemon is run). For more insights see [Linux containers on Windows - the Inside Story](https://dockercon.docker.com/watch/U7Bxp66uKmemZssjCTyXkm) and [this blogpost](https://forums.docker.com/t/linux-container-on-windows-docker-host/25884/2).

> Is the future architecture to have multiple vms, each hosting one container?

Do you mean if each linux container on Windows host starts its own MobyLinuxVM? Quoting [the Blogpost](https://blog.docker.com/2017/11/docker-for-windows-17-11/) again that `every time you start a Linux container Docker launches a minimal Hyper-V hypervisor running a VM with a Linux kernel, runc and the container processes running on top.`.

I tried under Windows 17.03 (so the old way) with Docker for Windows Version 17.12.0-ce-win47 (15139) that only one MobyLinuxVM is created, even when running multiple linux docker containers.

Answer (score 2):

> MobyLinuxVM Does this vm was build with Linuxkit?

MobyLinux is the predecessor of LinuxKit

> Is the future architecture to have multiple vms, each hosting one container?

That's how LCOW currently works (although the "VMs" are not user-visible - the fact that there's an actual hypervisor VM involved to run the container is an implementation detail).